# What happened to the other androids in Dragon Ball/Dragon Ball Z?

Tags: dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball

In *Dragon Ball Z*, we are well acquainted with Androids 16, 17, and 18. In addition, we met Androids 19 and 20 (Dr. Gero) before 16-18. There may have been mention of others, but they were not developed or mentioned much to the extent of my memory.

I also think that we were introduced to Android 8 in *Dragon Ball* (the episode where Goku is ascending up the Muscle Tower with a new foe on each floor, one of which was Ninja Murasaki who on finding himself outmatched, ordered Android 8 to fight Goku, if I remember correctly).

However, I do not remember any mention of Androids 1-7, 9-15, and 21+, if they exist. Do they exist? Do we ever find out or know what happened to them? Is it further discussed in the manga?

Comment: Androids 19 and 20 were shown in Dragonball Z as the first Androids that appeared. i believe 19 was actually Doctor Gero who Bulma identified when Future Trunks revealed that he wasn't one of the Androids which destroyed his time and the Z Warriors began looking for his lab to stop 17 and 18 from being activated. 20 was defeated by Vegeta after Goku contracted the heart disease (remember it was that plump white skinned one Vegeta ripped the arms off from)

Comment: @Memor-X Duly noted, I updated the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [Wikia](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Ribbon_Androids) and my memory, **Androids 1-7 and 9-12** were useless due to them being faulty (design problems) and some were too emotional and the kind.

As for **Android 8 a.k.a. Eighter or Hat-San**, as you rightly said, he had been depicted in the *Dragon Ball* manga, anime and the movies.

Now, **Android 13-15** were introduced in the 7th movie, *Dragon Ball Z: Super Android 13!* and were the first few killing machines built successfully with the aim of killing *Goku*.

Regarding **Androids 21+**, I'd like to state the [Wikia](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Ribbon_Androids). They have been portrayed in *Dragon Ball Fusions*, *Dragon Ball Heroes* etc.

#### Android 44

> An Android in *Dragon Ball Fusions* whose design bears resemblance to Android 20.

#### Android 8000

> A highly advanced variant of Android 8, utilized by the Time Breakers, comes in several different models including Mk. II and MX.

#### Android 19000

> A highly advanced variant of Android 19, built by the revived Gero and utilized by the Time Breakers.

---

Other than this, there's the ***Android A-B-C*** section which was in the *DBZ* manga if I recall correctly, which has all the information about the Androids up till Cell.

> [image: Android A-B-C from Dragon Ball Z]

That's pretty much all there is in the manga.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Wikia](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Ribbon_Androids), Android 1-7 and 9-12 were completely artificial but Gero could not control their personalities.

Answer (score 1):

Dr. Gero starts at 8 because it's a reference to *Dr. Slump* (Toriyama's 1st Hit). The main villain of the manga (Dr. Mashirito, a reference to Toriyama's editor) created 7 androids called "Caramel man". (Later he modified himself to caramel man 8 and 9).

Toriyama decided to continue from 8 for constructed androids.